# How do I resolve "failed to create interpreter" in pycharm pro in linux(ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I recently  ported into the linux os , any time I try to create a new flask project or any other project it doesn't install the package but it shows 'failed to create interpreter' .
Although I can manually set the interpreter up,but I would like a smoother workflow. My guess is that the problem should not be from pycharm but rather how ubuntu is configured.

The version of the pycharm pro is pycharm-2022.1.2
Python version is 3.10.2.
Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS .

[image]

Comment: Does that virtualenv directory exist?

Comment: No it does not exist, what am I expected to do. I thought pycharm should create it.Please what is making it not to create it?

Comment: I don't use Pycharm but you have to add an interpreter and have it create the virtualenv: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env. I don't know if you were expecting it to create a venv behind the scenes automatically (don't think it does that).

Comment: By default it should generate it for you,but a packaging tool was missing (distutils.utils).Hence I installed it. That fixed everything,

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install python3-distutils` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be caused by a bad installation of Pycharm or an absence of the Java package. If you are using the version of Pycharm provided on the JetBrains website, this behavior is normal and I advise you to install Pycharm via snap. To do so, execute the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic
```

If you have installed Pycharm this way, this error may come from your Java version. At this moment type this command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

If none of this worked, uninstall Pycharm: `sudo snap remove pycharm-professional`. Then reinstall it.